# GHC Linker error (stack)

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc, haskell-stack

I'm somewhat of a beginner in Haskell and I'm trying out [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) to build an application.

However, `stack build` gives me linker errors when executed:

```
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/sim-exe/sim-exe ...
[...]/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/libHSsim-0.1.0.0-EmdGqYS9bXF9VefempSPEG.a(Lib.o):(.text+0x98f5): undefined reference to `simzuEmdGqYS9bXF9VefempSPEG_Linter_lint_info'
[...]/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/libHSsim-0.1.0.0-EmdGqYS9bXF9VefempSPEG.a(Lib.o):(.data+0x5f0): undefined reference to `simzuEmdGqYS9bXF9VefempSPEG_Linter_lint_closure'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Looking at the labels tells me it's related to a closure in this function:

```
lint :: String -> [LintError]
lint source = let
  handleParseError :: ParseError -> [LintError]
  handleParseError e = [LintError (fromSourcePos $ errorPos e) $ format e]
  in
    case parseSim source of
      (Left error) -> handleParseError error
      (Right prog) -> lintProgram prog
```

But there's not really a closure in there? If I replace the implementation of `lint` with

```
lint _ = []
```

it compiles fine.

I can execute `stack ghci` and play around with the full `lint` implementation just fine. Why does it fail to link?

Comment: Probably the module is not included into the cabal file?

Comment: @Yuras yep, that was it... I added the module under `exposed-modules` and it works now - I simply didn't know I had to do that. Thanks

Comment: @DeX3 Could you please write that as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As yuras correctly pointed out, adding the module under `exposed-modules` in the cabal file resolves the issue.